# Is there a way to use multiple libraries built with Golang without crashing?

Tags: go

What I am really trying to do with a Go 1.18 app is load a static library (also written with Go) built using -buildmode=c-archive. The app only builds when using `#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`. And when I run the app, I get:

> fatal: morestack on g0

I also tried static linking a C++ app with multiple Go libraries and got the same fatal error at runtime. The C++ app also had to be linked with the same LDFLAGS I had used with cgo.

And not sure if this makes a difference, but I am doing this on Windoze.

I would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks!!!

Comment: No, you cannot load multiple instances of the Go runtime in the same process.

Comment: Go shared libraries should not be created for **use with go**.